# Python - get-pip.py not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell

I have saved the pip source file from the pip website but when I click to open it (from the browser on chrome) it says it can't find it on the desktop (where I saved it). And it is clearly there on the desktop.

I then tried to start pip in the terminal.

This is what I typed in the terminal and then the result which I received:

```
PS C:\Users\Kyle> pip
Program 'get-pip.py' failed to execute: Application not found
At line:1 char:4
+ pip <<<< .
At line:1 char:1
+  <<<< pip
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I found it interesting that I only typed pip yet it said: 'get-pip.py' failed to execute.
I have also tried changing the 'get-pip.py' file location and tried changing the `PATH` variable.
I am running python 2.7.3 on windows 7.

Does anyone have any idea where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score -2):

This is an interesting coincidence with Windows PowerShell which uses the [`get-<something>` convetion to name the PowerShell cmdlets that *retrieve a resource*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.verbscommon.get(v=vs.85).aspx). There's a shorthand way to call get commandlets by ommiting the `get-` part. That's why it tries to run the file with PowerShell by just typing `pip` and of course it fails.

You should run pip install using:

```
python get-pip.py
```

See [docs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip).

Comment: `PS C:\Users\Kyle> python get-pip.py
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` was what I got by entering that.

Comment: @Kyle Did you try to redownload the file to ensure that it's alright? Can you open it and see the Python source? Since you describe a weird download behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much... what you said I had already tried but I tried it again and then found that I could run it with git. I now have pip working in my terminal!

Comment: @Kyle Glad you fixed it. Well, at least I explained the PowerShell confusion.